# Python OpenCV Doesn't Support Codec

Tags: python, opencv

I am running into strange problems with the Python wrapper for OpenCV.  I am using the cv2 binding and have been able to do a lot with it but the latest problem is my inability to create a `VideoWriter`.

When I try to create a video writer using this command:

```
cv2.VideoWriter('foo.out.mov', cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('m','p','4','v'), 25, (704, 480), 1)
```

I get the following error:

```
error: /builddir/build/BUILD/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp:483:     error: (-210) Gstreamer Opencv backend doesn't support this codec acutally. in function CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open
```

When create a `VideoCapture` I can successfully retrieve frames by using the read method, but any calls to the get method to retrieve parameters such as frame width, frame height, or FOURCC code all return *0.0*.

I wanted to get the exact codec from the file I am opening to pass this into VideoWriter, but since this only returns 0.0 I don't know what to do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing -1 as the fourcc parameter. This should pop up a dialog and let you choose a video codec. I use it this way, and works great.

```
cv2.VideoWriter('foo.out.mov', -1, 25, (704, 480), 1)
```

Comment: So sorry to just get back to you on this.  Your solution did not work as I was in Linux, but I was able to get this working by completely reinstalling OpenCV.